# Delete commit which is merged into main branch

Tags: git, github, branch

How to delete this purple commit and the "Merge branch..." commit.
I try to using "git rebase -i HEAD~x" but not work.

[image]

Comment: `but not work.` - Where does it fail and what is the output?

Comment: @BVengerov the purple commit does not appear when run "git -rebase -i"

Comment: Did you try a `git rebase -p -i`? (`-p` for "preserve merge")

Comment: Supposing the 'Merge' commit is A, and the one below 'Initial commit' is B, and the current branch is master, you could try `git rebase --onto B A master`. But I'm afraid there will be conflicts if any file introduced by 'Initial commit' has been modified and committed after the merge.

Comment: did you mean A, B are hashes number of commits?

Comment: @yelliver yes, they refer to commit hash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this kind of magic with `git fast-export` (after you made a backup of your working copy):
Run `git fast-export --no-data --all --full-tree > all_commits` in your working copy. Then you open the file all_commits in a text editor, and  search for "initial commit". The environment around it should look like this:

```
commit refs/heads/master
mark :110
author Foo Bar <foobar@example.org> 1462192582 +0100
committer Foo Bar <foobar@example.org> 1462192582 +0100
data 14
Initial Commit
deleteall
M 100644 b346ed4d2db0c8110fe3104bd155a413b878527c some/file

commit refs/heads/master
mark :111
author Foo Bar <foobar@example.org> 1462192582 +0100
committer Foo Bar <foobar@example.org> 1462192582 +0100
data 21
Merge branch 'master'
from :109
merge :110
deleteall
M 100644 b346ed4d2db0c8110fe3104bd155a413b878527c some/file
M 100644 4d9af842ccf23b883b234f5ae93d71f11fa285de some/other_file

commit refs/heads/master
mark :112
author Foo Bar <foobar@example.org> 1462192582 +0100
committer Foo Bar <foobar@example.org> 1462192582 +0100
data 14
Did some stuff
from :111
deleteall
M 100644 b346ed4d2db0c8110fe3104bd155a413b878527c some/file
M 100644 d6a0ad80d11b9d376c23d17300ce95d724d050e7 some/other_file
```

You cut out that commit, by removing the commit block and adjustment of the references (`mark` places a reference to a commit to identify it later, and `from` or `merge` identify the parents of a commit):

```
commit refs/heads/master
mark :111
author Foo Bar <foobar@example.org> 1462192582 +0100
committer Foo Bar <foobar@example.org> 1462192582 +0100
data 21
Merge branch 'master'
from :109
deleteall
M 100644 b346ed4d2db0c8110fe3104bd155a413b878527c some/file
M 100644 4d9af842ccf23b883b234f5ae93d71f11fa285de some/other_file

commit refs/heads/master
mark :112
author Foo Bar <foobar@example.org> 1462192582 +0100
committer Foo Bar <foobar@example.org> 1462192582 +0100
data 14
Did some stuff
from :111
deleteall
M 100644 b346ed4d2db0c8110fe3104bd155a413b878527c some/file
M 100644 d6a0ad80d11b9d376c23d17300ce95d724d050e7 some/other_file
```

Than you import your changed stream with `git fast-import --force < all_commits`. After this operation, the offending commit is gone.

When something went wrong, you can recover your original commits with `git fast-import --force < all_commits.backup`, but it is not a bad idea to create a backup before this operation.

Comment: +1. 'do this kind of magic' is aptly mentioned. This type of operation is usually not done in a typical workflow and alters history (which can be very bad if others pull from this branch).`git revert` is usually a more apt solution to 'undo' that commit.

Comment: great! It's not only can delete any commit but also can change email & info & many other things. Btw, can you rebase, merge or some complex activities by using git fast-export?

Comment: And my "Initial commit" has the line "Initial commitdeleteall" without space before "deleteall", is it strange?

Comment: @yelliver The commit message is encoded in the `data N` block, where N is the number of bytes of the message. When there was no line feed in the original commit message, then this is the normal behavior. When you want to change the commit message, I recommend not to use the fixed length data format, but the delimited format (see `git help fast-import` for the format description).

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

or

```
git reset --hard <sha1-commit-id>
```

If you already pushed it

```
git push origin HEAD --force
```

Comment: which commit should I get the <sha1-commit-id>? is it the purple commit?

Comment: you can find it using git log

Comment: I think this does not answer the question as @yelliver only wants to remove one commit from the history (if I understand his question correct), while `git reset --hard` will remove all commits following <sha1-commit-id>.

Answer (score 0):

You can do by rebasing commits which are to be preserved on top of last valid commit. For finding commits to be preserved, create two branches `tmp_1, tmp_2`. `HEAD` of both these branches will point to endpoints of commits to be preserved.

Now, rebase these commits on top of last valid commit. Force rename the master after successful rebase.

```
git checkout -b tmp_1
git checkout -b tmp_2 <sha-of-commit-after-merged-one>
git checkout -b tmp_3 <sha-of-commit-before-merged-one>
git rebase --onto tmp3 tmp_2 tmp_1
```

After successful rebase,

`git branch -f master tmp_3`

Delete other branches.

Answer (score 0):

You can revert that commit using below command:
git revert < Sha1 >